# Adding protobuf in yocto recipe

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c, yocto-recipe

How can we add protobuf specific version (say : 3.19.6) in the yocto recipe?

what are the things that we can add in the yocto recipe to install protobuf 3.19.6

Answer (score 0):

Add the [meta-openembedded](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded) layer to `build/conf/bblayers.conf`, and then add e.g. `DEPENDS="protobuf-c"` (or `DEPENDS="protobuf-c-native` , depending on what you want to do) to your recipe.